# Need help refactoring a LINQ statement with a Group By clause?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, .net-4.0, group-by

The Linq-To-SQL that needs refactoring is found below:

```
   var query = from p in Cache.Model.Products
               join sc in Cache.Model.ShishaCombinations on p.ProductID equals sc.ProductID
               where sc.NumberOfMixes ==  mixes
               select new { p.ProductID, p.Name };
```

with the following one-liner:

```
   group by p.ProductID
```

I know that group by omits any need for the select clause so both can live together in the same LINQ-To-SQL statement so can someone help me refactor the above please?

To help me remove any repeating data in my results. <-- This is the entire point in this question. A product is repeated a number of times based on the number of Flavours that are used by the product. So as a result in the 'ShishaCombinations' table one ProductID may be repeated many times one for each flavour that it uses. I would like to group the results returned from the query above or call distinct on it as I don't want add the product 'n' times to my GUI because it appears 'n' number of times in my results. Hopefully that will clear up any confusion of what I am trying to do.

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean by "To-SQL found below refactoring". You can't *just* group, given that you need the NumberOfMixes property.

Comment: (It would probably help your question to be clearer if you'd show what results you're trying to get.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below is all what I needed:

```
        var query1 = (from p in Cache.Model.Products
                     join sc in Cache.Model.ShishaCombinations on p.ProductID equals sc.ProductID
                     where sc.NumberOfMixes == mixes
                     select new { p.ProductID, p.Name }).Distinct();
```

Ufuk, thanks for answering mate. I knew my answer was a simple one lol : )

Answer (score 0):

You can use into keyword after select clause. You cannot just group by because you are projecting an anonymous type.

```
   var query = from p in Cache.Model.Products
               join sc in Cache.Model.ShishaCombinations on p.ProductID equals sc.ProductID
               where sc.NumberOfMixes ==  mixes
               select new { p.ProductID, p.Name } into productInfo
               group productInfo by productInfo.productId;
```

Comment: Seems to work but no joy? I understand perfectly what you said in your answer but your query returns the exact same results as mine even without the group by clause? : S

Comment: @IbrarMumtaz Then I guess your ProductID column is the the unique ID so grouping on that column does nothing. Since you don't use elements on IGrouping interface it's surely unneccessary. What do you want to do exactly?